# Scala Error: value registerTempTable is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I want to  read a Parquet file. I write this code in spark-shell:

```
val logFile = "hdfs://byd0085/"
val sqlContext=new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val parquetFile = sqlContext.parquetFile(logFile)
parquetFile.registerTempTable("parquetFile")
```

By calling `parquetFile.registerTempTable("parquetFile")`, there is a error `error: value registerTempTable is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD`
. But parquetFile is indeed a SchemaRDD and registerTempTable is indeed a function of org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD. I'm new to Scala and Spark and I can't figure out the reason.  Anyone can help?

Spark Version 1.0.0
Scala Version 2.10.4

Comment: What version of Spark are you using? SchemaRDD is now DataFrame, so this tells me it is 1.2 or older at least

Comment: @JustinPihony , just updated, thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[In Spark 1.0, this was called `registerAsTable`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD)

Answer (score 2):

`people.toDF()` will convert RDD to dataframes.

```
 val s= people.toDF()
 s.registerTempTable("people")
```

or

```
people.toDF().registerTempTable("people")
```

Answer (score 0):

error: value registerAsTable is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[People]
              people.registerTempTable("People")

Comment: Could you expand on this answer at all? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Method

> `registerTempTable`

in class Dataset is deprecated: Use

> `createOrReplaceTempView`

(viewName) instead.